# Can I set a default test_arg for go_tests and override from CLI?

Tags: bazel

I use gazelle to generate BUILD files for a go package that has some non-go directories.

I'd like to add -test.short to the go_test runs by default, and then turn it back off, optionally, from CLI.

Adding --test_arg="-test.short" to the CLI does not work, since it gets passed to the non-Go tests.

If I could add something to WORKSPACE that modified the default args for go_test based on a select, I'd be good here. Or if I could persuade gazelle to generate my_go_test instead of go_test, I could do some Skylark. Am I missing any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Bazel's [`config_setting`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting) and [`select`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select) to make this work. `config_setting` lets you define a predicate which is true or false, depending on command-line arguments. You can provide a `--define` argument that the `config_setting` will test. Then you can optionally pass an argument to tests using `select`.

Something like this might work for you. This will pass the `-test.short` argument to the test if you pass `--define=short=true` on the command line. No argument would be passed by default.

```
config_setting(
    name = "short",
    values = {
        "define": "short=true",
    },
)

go_test(
    name = "go_default_test",
    srcs = ["hello_test.go"],
    args = select({
        ":short": ["-test.short"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
)
```